# I tried to move the matlab to scilab syntax for genetic algorithms, but the selection function had an error. like this

Tags: scilab

function [best1, best2] = selection(population)

```
fitness = zeros(1,length(population));
for i=1:length(population)
    fitness(i) = population(i).fitness;
end

[~,index] = max(fitness);
best1 = population(index);

population(index) = [];
fitness(index) = [];

[~,index] = max(fitness);
best2 = population(index);
```

endfunction

Answer (score 0):

[~,index] = max(fitness);
^
Error: syntax error, unexpected ","

Answer (score 0):

The syntax using "~" when you don't want to assign an output parameter is not available in Scilab. You have to use a dummy variable, e.g.

```
[dummy,index] = max(fitness)
```